# use of filter() method to delete a row from a todo list

Tags: reactjs, filter

I'm a bit stuck on filtering a ToDo list, with the ultimate goal of deleting a completed To Do.

I was successful in passing the `deleteTodo()` method to the child Component `Todo`, and also in retrieving the `index` of the Todo to delete.

However, I tried to move forward and use the `filter` method to filter the list of Todos and filter out the deleted one (I don't want to use slice, but practice with `filter()`), but I am not succeeding in using it.

I have 2 files, App.js and the child component ToDo.js

Thanks!

App.js (for full code: https://codeshare.io/24n7Yj)

```
 deleteTodo(index) {
      const todos = this.state.todos.filter();
      const todo = todos[index];
      this.setState({ todos: todos });
    }
```

ToDo.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ToDo extends Component { //define a class that extends Component
   render() {
   return (
       <li>
          <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.props.isCompleted } onChange={ this.props.toggleComplete } />
          <span>{ this.props.description }</span>
          <button onClick ={this.props.deleteTodo}>Delete</button>
       </li>
   );
 }
}

export default ToDo; //the component is made to export the data
```

Answer (score 1):

The array method `filter` takes a function as first argument that is invoked with each element in the array, and the element's index. You can return `true` for all elements except the one with the same index as the one you pass in to the `deleteTodo` method.

```
deleteTodo(index) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const todos = prevState.todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index);

    return { todos };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a callback function as an argument. It will go through each element giving you the element and it's index. You can filter out the one you want by doing the following and checking if the index is the same as the one provided :

```
deleteTodo = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        todos: prevState.todos.filter((todo, i) => i !== index)
    }));
}
```